laravel's matchory/elasticsearch scroll_id is missing
In searching via laravel's matchory/elasticsearch, I used simple ->take(10000)->skip(n) method, but eventually got the following error:
"Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [20000]. See the scroll API for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting."
The ideal solution would be to use "scroll" method, described here in section "Scan-and-Scroll queries":
https://www.larablocks.com/package/matchory/elasticsearch
But, it does not work, I can not find how to get scroll_id, mentioned in the doc without an example.

How to get it?


$batch = $this
    ->esType
    ->body(["_source" => ["_id"]])
    ->scroll("5m")
    ->take(10000)
    ->get(); 

After trying what I could and looking at source code, I found in var_dump($batch) named scroll id scrollId instead of scroll_id and it is a protected variable. Correct way to get it turned out to be:
$scrollId = $batch->getScrollId();

The following queries to get next and next 10000 items then would be:
$batch = $this
    ->esType
    ->body(["_source" => ["_id"]])
    ->scroll("5m")
    ->scrollID($scrollId)
    ->get();              

